# Extremely large enumerators (> 64 bits types)

Tags: c++, enums, 64-bit

TL;DR How many elements could an enumerator hold, and would that number be larger than a 64-bit or 96-bit number?

In my experience with C and C++, I've found that the largest variable type that will compile is 96 bits (12 bytes) and even that is a non-standard addition by GCC 64 bit. So, I started thinking about enumerators and how large an enumerator could be. Let's say, for the sake of simplicity, I have an enumerator-type called foo:

```
enum foo
{
    //Insert types here
}
```

And that we have the enumerator filled with an ENORMOUS amount of types:

```
enum foo
{
    type1,
    type2,
    type3,
        //Some keyboard-time later....
    type9999999999999999999999999999999999999997,
    type9999999999999999999999999999999999999998,
    type9999999999999999999999999999999999999999,
    type10000000000000000000000000000000000000000 //That's fifty zeroes
}
```

Would that even compile? (Yes,I know compilation would give me a good idea of how long an ice age lasts, but still) And would I be able to declare a `foo` with the value of every single one of the `type`s?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This sounds like an X-Y question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: "*the largest variable type that will compile is 96 bits (12 bytes)*" -- `char[1024]` is a lot bigger than 96 bits.

Comment: You don't need a huge number of constants to get a huge constant value. `enum foo { big = 1000000, bigger };`

Comment: Well, I simply need an EXTREMELY large counter variable for a time-capsule like item. I know that a 64 bit number would hold a _lot_ of time, but I just need to be sure.

Comment: If you're declaring 96 bit enums like that the source file would have to be at least 393216 yotta bytes...

Comment: How big of a number to you expect to count up to?

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the rules are different in C, where all the constants have to be within the range of type `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the standard:

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying type is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. **If no integral type can represent all the enumerator values, the enumeration is ill-formed.**

So for standard conforming compiler the program should not compile if there is no integral type that can hold all the enumerator values.

This is from the working draft https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard, but I doubt that part has changed.